# Caffe Python3 Installation

Tags: python-3.5, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to install caffe cpu only on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and python 3.5 (Ubuntu installed on virtual box)

I edited Makefile.config as follow:

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA >= 9.0, comment the *_20 and *_21 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
#PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
#       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python-py35 python3.5m
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
                 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# NCCL acceleration switch (uncomment to build with NCCL)
# https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl (last tested version: v1.2.3-1+cuda8.0)
# USE_NCCL := 1

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

# N.B. both build and distribute dirs are cleared on `make clean`
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

Then I build all and i build pycaffe and the test (make runtest) was done succefully:

```
make all
make test
make runtest
sudo cp build/lib/libcaffe.so* /usr/lib
make pycaffe
sudo cp -r python/caffe/ /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
```

when I try :

```
python3 -c "import caffe"
```

I got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 15, in <module>
    import caffe.io
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/caffe/io.py", line 2, in <module>
    import skimage.io
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    reset_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 93, in reset_plugins
    _load_preferred_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 73, in _load_preferred_plugins
    _set_plugin(p_type, preferred_plugins['all'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 85, in _set_plugin
    use_plugin(plugin, kind=plugin_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 255, in use_plugin
    _load(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 299, in _load
    fromlist=[modname])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/matplotlib_plugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 37, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._subplots import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as _  # <-registers a date unit converter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 125, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 55
    raise ValueError, "Can't create weekday with n == 0"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> Reference:
>   https://github.com/dungba88/caffe-python3-install/blob/master/install-caffe.md

Comment: did you add caffe path to $PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Thank you, To fix this error I did :`pip install python-dateutil --upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

i have compiled caffe on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS both with python 2 and python, it is really a hectic process for beginners, for caffe with python 2.7 make sure that your /.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages only contains a version same as you protoc version. protoc version can be checked by entering

`protoc --version`

for me i got problems with python 2.7 because by mistake i installed protbuf 3.0 alpha in python 2.7 site packages, so there was a protobuf error after removing it from python 2.7 site packages everything worked fine
also install python-dev version

`apt-get install the python3.x-dev`

and for python 3.5 make sure you have python 3.0 alpha, if you have both python 2.7 and python 3.x in the system use pip3 otherwise use pip

`pip3 install protobuf==3.0.0-alpha-3`

or another protobuf such as 3.5 version of protobuf.
also do this

`pip3 install python-dateutil --upgrade`

after that do

`make clean`

`make all -j8`
`make runtest -j8`

`make pycaffe`

after performing make all make runtest steps don't forget to do that

`sudo ldconfig`

hope everything works OK for you.

Comment: Thanks I implemented using python3